# Why $(x-vt)^2$ does not represent a wave?

Tags: waves, definition

My textbook says that any function which can be written as $y(x,t)=f(ax±b)$ represents a wave. It says that that the only condition is that it should be finite everywhere and at all times.

With this definition, I cannot understand why $(x-vt)^2$ does not represent a wave. It is finite for all real $x$ and $t$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should a solution to the wave equation be finite?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155995/)

Comment: mathematically infinity is part of the "everywhere"  and there your function is not finite. read the link given byYashas

Comment: Mathematically, infinity does not exist.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity#Calculus "Infinity can be used not only to define a limit but as a value in the extended real number system."

Comment: Alright. Then this equation should be able to define wave motion before t=infinity. Right?

Comment: not if one obeys the statement  "only condition is that it should be finite everywhere and at all times."

Comment: again, read the answer in the link by Yashas, it discusses the conventions